# Tikz: multi-line vertically aligned node

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes, matrices

Can I align these multi-line nodes vertically?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    fit,
    positioning,
    matrix,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    status/.style={rectangle, draw=black, text centered, text=black, minimum width=1.5em, minimum height=1.5em, font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
    m2style/.style={column sep=0.25em, row sep=0.1em, nodes={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0pt},
        row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
        row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=red}},
        row 3 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}},
        row 4 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        column 1/.append style={nodes={status}},
        column 2/.append style={nodes={text width=3.5em}},
    },
}
\matrix(m2)[matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&, m2style]{
    H  \& Healthy \\
    A1 \& Infected (strong) \\
    A2 \& Infected (weak) \\
    D  \& Death  \\
};
\node[above=-0.5ex of m2, font=\bfseries\footnotesize, text width=5em] (title) {Cell Status};
\node[draw=black, inner sep=0in, fit=(title) (m2)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Desired outcome:

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `anchor=center` to the node style, i.e. within `nodes={}` in `m2style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    fit,
    positioning,
    matrix,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    status/.style={rectangle, draw=black, text centered, text=black, minimum width=1.5em, minimum height=1.5em, font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
    m2style/.style={column sep=0.25em, row sep=0.1em, nodes={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0pt},
        row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
        row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=red}},
        row 3 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}},
        row 4 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray}},
        column 1/.append style={nodes={status,anchor=center}},
        column 2/.append style={nodes={text width=3.5em,anchor=center}},
    },
}
\matrix(m2)[matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&, m2style]{
    H  \& Healthy \\
    A1 \& Infected (strong) \\
    A2 \& Infected (weak) \\
    D  \& Death  \\
};
\node[above=-0.5ex of m2, font=\bfseries\footnotesize, text width=5em] (title) {Cell Status};
\node[draw=black, inner sep=0in, fit=(title) (m2)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```